# How can I do an "execution" in a Makefile?

Tags: bash, shell, testing, makefile

How can I do a run command (`./`) in a Makefile ?

The aim is to run shell scripts when I do `make test`

Here's the rule I tried, but not working :

```
test    :
        ./test/ls.sh
        ./test/ls_2.sh
```

But when I try it I have :

```
make: `test' is up to date.
```

Comment: That's because `test` already exists, so Make skips the recipe.

Comment: So.. Is there any way to force the Makefile to do this rule ?

Comment: use `.PHONY: test` or call the rule something else, something that isn't an already existing file/directory.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think i'm a little tired.. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a file or directory named `test`.
In such situations, with an empty list of dependencies,
`make` will do nothing and just report that the file is up to date,
as you have observed.

To tell make to execute the target anyway,
add it to the list of phony targets, like this:

```
.PHONY: test

test    :
        ./test/ls.sh
        ./test/ls_2.sh
```

You can read more about [Phony Targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) in the docs.